# Отсортировать массив по убыванию значений на javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Пример массива ["слон":5,"коза":1, "пингвин":3]
необходимо отсортировать по убыванию значения чтобы результат был таким:
["слон":5,"пингвин":3,"коза":1]

Comment: странный у вас массив

Comment: этот массив рабочий, да? Никаких ошибок нет?

Comment: результат объединения нескольких массивов  животных, в результате массив названий и количества упоминания животного

Comment: @СергейКолесников, а сами Вы решать пытались?.. можете показать что получилось?

Comment: вот рабочий массив в консоли браузера https://yadi.sk/i/lJx4s-8y3MYMWb

Comment: Сам решать пытался ничего не выходит, я  слаб в JS

Comment: Для начала тебе стоит поучить основы JS и узнать, что так массивы не пишутся. а вот после того как ты почитаешь основы и всё это узнаешь, может тогда стоит начинать что-то писать

Comment: Да мне стыдно но я прошу помощи

Comment: Нельзя отсортировать невалидный массив

Comment: Да ты батенька робот)) похоже

Answer (score 2):

можно сделать массив обьектов тогда можно будет отсортировать например так

```
var animal = [{
    exemplar: "слон",
    quantity: 5
}, {
    exemplar: "коза",
    quantity: 1
}, {
    exemplar: "пингвин",
    quantity: 3
}];
animal.sort((a, b) => a.quantity < b.quantity);
for (var i = 0; i < animal.length; i++) {
    console.log(animal[i].exemplar, animal[i].quantity);
}
```

а это так как ты не знаешь валидности массива то на русском

```
var животные = [{
    экземпляр: "слон",
    количество: 5
}, {
    экземпляр: "коза",
    количество: 1
}, {
    экземпляр: "пингвин",
    количество: 3
}];
животные.sort((a, b) => a.количество < b.количество);
for (var i = 0; i < животные.length; i++) {
      console.log(животные[i].экземпляр, животные[i].количество);
}
```

Comment: так сортировка работает как сортировка стороки

Answer (score 1):

полностью сделать так как в начальных условиях не получилось можно подготовить массив для сортировки и для дальнейших действий

```js
let arr = [];
arr["коза"] = 1;
arr["слон"] = 5;
arr["пингвин"] = 3;
console.log('начальный массив', arr);

let tmp = [];

// пересобетем в массив обьектов
for (var variable in arr) {
  tmp.push({
    animal: variable,
    count: arr[variable]
  });
}
// наша сотрировка
let as = tmp.sort((one, two) => {
  return two.count - one.count
});

// итоговый вывод
console.log(as);
```

> да в ошибки этой песочнице можно занести не отображение ассоциативного массива